# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit guest OS kernel panic on start up

Tags: vmware-workstation, ubuntu-14.04, vmware-player, init, kernel-panic

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64bit guest OS running on VMWare Workstation 12 Player on a Windows 10 host. I was running Eclipse for a while recently when it got really slow despite multiple Eclipse restarts, so I decided to reboot the guest OS. It froze on the GUI desktop either shutting down or booting up, so I rebooted down using VMWare. After this, I kept getting kernel panics with the following errors:

run-init: /sbin/init: No such file or directory Target filesyste doesn't have requested /sbin/init run-init: /sbin/init: No such file or directory run-init: /etc/init Permission denied run-init: /bin/init: No such file or directory

I think my filesystem must have been corrupted somehow. I tried to boot into a Live DVD by loading the 14.04 DVD ISO as the DVD drive and checking "Connect at power on". I then started the VM and selected the DVD drive in the boot menu. However, it still booted up from my hard drive.

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Is there any other way of accessing the guest OS file system? Perhaps by mounting the disk image which is probably somewhere in the VM files?

Answer (score 0):

**To try and recover without the ISO/DVD:**
Try powering on your VM and selecting "Recovery Options" from the GRUB menu (if present, otherwise see [this link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1534203)).

**Booting from the DVD/ISO:**
While the VM is powered off, go to the VM settings and select the CD as the primary/only boot device. Alternatively, if VMWare supports it (I've been using Virtualbox for so long so I don't recall), you can manually select your boot device at power on (usually something similar to a PC like F9).

Comment: I already tried option 1 and  that didn't work since I don't think it's a kernel problem but rather a file system problem(missing/corrupted init file and/or other system files. I don't see any options in VM settings to select the CD drive as the primary/only boot device. I did go into the BIOS once booted up via F2 and selected the CD drive as the first boot drive but that didn't seem to work. I also tried the boot menu via Esc no go either.

Comment: Only thing I can think of is:
1. Try another VM like Virtualbox which can import the VMWare hdd image see http://www.howtogeek.com/125640/how-to-convert-virtual-machines-between-virtualbox-and-vmware/

2. Create a new vitual machine and add the damaged image as a secondary hdd to repair it (fsck it for more).

3. What you suggested in the first comment **if** there is a tool to mount the image on your host OS.